# Is there a way to conditionally connect to specific Bluetooth devices?

Tags: bluetooth-audio

My devices involved are a Sena (Bluetooth receiver / speakers for helmet), the built in Moto Guzzi MIA (Bluetooth media module), and a Pixel 7 with Android Version 13.

To play music / handle phone calls from my phone, over the Sena speakers, and allow it to be controlled by the handlebar controls, both the phone and Sena connect to the motorcycle, but not each other.
This works fine, until I turn off the engine to refuel, or walk into a store for a couple minutes. During this time I would like the phone to automatically connect to the Sena to continue playing music / minimally interrupt a phone call, and once the motorcycle is on again, switch back.

Is there a way to handle this automatically, such that the phone only connects to the Sena if the motorcycle is not available, and once the motorcycle becomes available, will disconnect from the Sena before connecting to the motorcycle?

Comment: I don't have your kind of set up to verify but using [MacroDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid) try creating a [macro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qX4i8.png) //In the first action configure Moto Guzzi and in second one Sena//Save the macro and experiment with confidence levels//If it works fine post it as an answer yourself (it's encouraged)